# How do I display a UIImage from one ViewController in a second ViewController?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

So I set out thinking this would be pretty straight forward but I really can't figure out how to do this! Basically I'm using a TabBar Application so each page is governed by a `UITabBarController`. I have created a UIImage that displays when you select it from the Photo Library, I want that selection to display in a different view controller. This is the code I have in the first VC:

```
- (void)addNew:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked");
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller setDelegate:self];

    [self.photoView.view removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    NSLog(@"this function has started");
    [self.view setAlpha:1.0f];
    imageV1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageV1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, 100, 100);
    image1 = image;
    [imageV1 setImage:image];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageV1];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

So that displays the image in this view (which is not what I want). I want it to display in this view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];

    imageV2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 100)];
    imageV2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.imageV2.image = VC1.imageV1.image;
    [imageV2 setImage:VC1.image1];
[scrollView addSubview:imageV2];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

I've linked the two VC's by creating an instance of VC1

```
ViewControllerOne *VC1;

@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewControllerOne *VC1;
```

I hope I've explained this well, but to summarise I want to be able to display the UIImage in ViewController 2 when the UIImage is selected from the photolibrary that pops up in ViewController 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which VC is which and where each one is declared, but what I think youre saying is that you have an image and a newly declared VC within your initial VC. If thats the case I would create a view with your UIImage within your initial VC and then add it as a view or subview of your new VC.

```
    newView = [[UIView alloc]init] ;

    [newView addSubView:image1] ;
```

then either:

```
    [self.VC1.view addSubView:newView] ;
```

or:

```
    [self.VC1 setView:newView] ;
```

Sorry if I misunderstoon your question. Maybe try labeling which VC is which better and keeping it consistent?

Comment: Cool, I'll try that out and Get back to you. Thanks for the reply, I always find it hard ot explains these things unless im physically showing someone but thanks for the advice!